# My desktop reboots about every 5 minutes

Tags: 16.04, grub2, system, reboot

My desktop reboots about every 5 minutes, especially when navigating the Web and without any notice. No trace or hint on system and kernel logs. Can someone help me? Thx in advance

Comment: Have you checked if your CPU/GPU is overheating?

Comment: Reboot or power off?

Comment: No trace in the system or kernel logs leads me to infer that your hardware fails so suddenly and completely that the OS has no time to notice. Check your fans, ventilation, and budget. If you have overheated your computer severely, it will be forever unreliable.

Comment: How can i check CPU/GPU temperature? @Android Dev

Comment: The other matter is that everything started to happen soon after upgrading from 14.04 LTS to 16.04. Any suggestion?

Comment: Boot the machine from a live CD to see if it is the hardware or not. If it's OK with a live CD, something is awry with the installation. If you still have the problem, it's a hardware fault.